# Elasticsearch 6.3 - How to Sort on an Analyzed field?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

So, I have found examples of this for older versions of Elastic, but due to the syntax changing, I haven't been able to translate those solutions into the 6.3 Syntax.

I have a field, ShowName (String), which I have applied an N-Gram Analyzer to. The problem is that I also need to sort by that field. Before I added the analyzer, I got the Keyword suffix sub property and was able to sort no bother, however, since adding the analyzer, I now don't have access to that keyword sub property.

I have tried decorating the property in my model with both the `[Text(Analyzer = "nGram_analyzer")])` and `Keyword` properties, but when creating the index I get an error saying:

> Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.

I then tried explicitly adding both fields in the mappings while creating my index (code below) and while this creates both fields, I am still unable to sort by the keyword suffixed field. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(shows, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .TokenFilters(t => t.NGram("nGram_filter", ng => ng.MinGram(3).MaxGram(10)))
                    .Analyzers(aa => aa
                        .Custom("nGram_analyzer", cc => cc
                            .Tokenizer("whitespace")
                            .Filters(nGramFilters1)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<ShowElasticSearchModel>(m => m
                    .AutoMap<ShowElasticSearchModel>()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.ShowName)
                            .Analyzer("nGram_analyzer")
                            .Fields(fs => fs
                                .Text(tt => tt.Name(nn => nn.ShowName.Suffix("keyword")))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Edit: Following on from the answer received, the final syntax for the code block is as follows (now contains multiple Multi Fields within the code).

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(shows, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .TokenFilters(t => t.NGram("nGram_filter", ng => ng.MinGram(3).MaxGram(10)))
                    .Analyzers(aa => aa
                        .Custom("nGram_analyzer", cc => cc
                            .Tokenizer("whitespace")
                            .Filters(nGramFilters1)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<ShowElasticSearchModel>(m => m
                    .AutoMap<ShowElasticSearchModel>()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.ShowName)
                            .Analyzer("nGram_analyzer")
                            .Fields(ff => ff
                                .Keyword(k => k
                                    .Name(n => n.ShowName.Suffix("keyword"))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Organisation)
                            .Analyzer("nGram_analyzer")
                            .Fields(ff => ff
                                .Keyword(k => k
                                    .Name(n => n.Organisation.Suffix("keyword"))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Venues)
                            .Analyzer("nGram_analyzer")
                            .Fields(ff => ff
                                .Keyword(k => k
                                    .Name(n => n.Venues.Suffix("keyword"))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` field type has been [split](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) to [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) types since Elasticsearch 5.0. `Text` fields can't be used for sorting, so you need to create [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html): with type `text` for full text search and with type `keyword` for aggregations and sorting.

But in your example you create two `text` fields, and use `keyword` as field name suffix rather than field type (as far as I can understand `C#` syntax).

Comment: This was the explanation I needed! It took a little bit of fiddling about to get the exact syntax, but thank you for the pointers. Exact syntax is in the question now.

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I don't know `C#` well, so it was difficult to me to provide exact code snippet.

Comment: I've added the code snippet that I used to the original question. Your advice was more than enough to point me in the right direction :)